# Group multiple reports into one in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I'm new to SSRS and I need the ability to group multiple reports into a single report. I've searched around a lot but not found much. I currently have two reports (more to come) that users need to be able to view/save individually. The users also need the option to view both those reports as a single report. Essentially just a simple concatenation. Eventually, there will be several reports grouped and the user will be able to render all of them for viewing online or saving as a single PDF.

I tried two sub-reports in a master report but it causes a lot of hard to diagnose page-break problems. I was wondering if there was a more straight forward option here. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Combining all the report elements into one report would work, but the users also need to be able to view them as individual reports as well. To avoid having to maintain both an master report and multiple individual reports, you have a couple of options:

1. Create a master report and insert the individual reports as sub-reports. If you get page break issues, check the report page height and widths versus the subreport container height and width.
2. (If you have SQL Server 2008 R2 or later) Consider publishing your individual reports as a set of Report Parts. You can then reuse these in a master report.

Comment: Didn't know about the Report Parts ability. I'm running Express everything right now though so I'll have to try that later. I've cleaned up my report, body and margins but the only way I can get rid of the extra pages is if the problem report fills the entire body of the master as a sub-report. But then there is no room for other reports. Best I've done so far is to position the two sub-reports in opposite corners, I only get 4 extra pages that way.

Comment: After much trial and error I finally got things working. It appears you do not want any white-space in the master report as that will get repeated (a guess but seems to work). You then must tweak sub-report sizes to be a bit smaller than your master.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a fan of subreports either, they work well in Crystal but are not really necessary in reporting services.

Why don't you just combine the reports into one? Copy all the tablixes / other objects from each report onto a new report. You can select all and copy and paste very easily, you just need to set up the parameters, datasets and data sources if they aren't shared.
You can set pagebreaks to occur after each tablix or a good trick is to use rectangles because they will let you control page breaks in their properties.

Comment: Fair enough if people want to downvote this, but at least be brave enough to write your reason. It's not helpful to the community to hit and run downvote.

Comment: But not sure, why it is showing 4 print pages when there is only one page break ... :(